# Sorting column label pandas pivot table

Tags: python, pandas

Another pandas sort question (tried all current SO ones and didn't find any solutions).

I have a `pandas pivot_table` like so:

```
rows = ['Tool_Location']
cols = ['shift_date','Part_Number', 'shift']
pt = df.pivot_table(index='Tool_Location', values='Number_of_parts', dropna=False, fill_value ='0', columns=cols, aggfunc='count')
```

produces:

```
Shift date     10/19
Part_number   40001
shift        first  second  third
tool_loc
T01            0     1     0       
T02            2     1     0
```

I'd like to switch the order of shift labels so it is `third first second`

**EDIT:**

Getting closer to a solution but not seeing it.

Using:

```
 col_list = pt.columns.tolist()
 output:
 [('10/20/16', 'first'), ('10/20/16', 'second'), ('10/20/16', 'third'), ('10/21/16', 'first'), ('10/21/16', 'second'), ('10/21/16', 'third')]
```

Anyone know how to dynamically reorder the items so its:

```
[('10/20/16', 'third'), ('10/20/16', 'first'), ('10/20/16', 'second'), ('10/21/16', 'first'), ('10/21/16', 'second'), ('10/21/16', 'second')]
```

Because then we could reorder the columns by using pt = pt[col_list]

Comment: If you could add your original data before the pivot at the start of the question that would  make it easier to understanding because you only show the transformation we have to guess the staring point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lambda and dict to sort your tuples:

```
pt = pt[sorted(df.columns.tolist(), key=lambda tup: list(your_dict.keys())[list(your_dict.values()).index(tup[1])])]
```

To do this, you have also declare a dict with needed order:

```
your_dict = {1: 'first', 3: 'third', 2: 'second'}
```

Answer (score 2):

`df.pivot_table` produces a dataframe. What if you do something like this after your lines:

```
pt = pt[["third","first","second"]]
```

Comment: Giving me a `KeyError at /tooltrack/summary/
"['third' 'first' 'second'] not in index"`

Comment: just change 'second' to 'sec'.  From looking at the dataframe above

Comment: Sorry - it is actually 'second' in the dataframe, I typo'd the example.